# Type content inside contenteditable, outside child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable div:

```
<div contenteditable="true"><strong>Hi there</strong></div>
```

When I type something inside it, all the texts are bold. I checked using Inspect Element and it seems that everything typed goes inside "strong" tag but I want it to be outside of it, inside div tag. How do I fix this problem?

```css
div {
  height: 250px;
  }
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true"><strong>Hi there</strong></div>
```

Comment: Do you want the text to not be bold typing before "Hi there" or after it?

Comment: Everywhere else. Main issue "was" that all the text was being inserted inside strong element, and not in div. @Josh Burgess answer fixed the problem for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix that simply by setting `contenteditable="false"` on the `<strong>` element.

```css
div {
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true"><strong contenteditable="false">Hi there</strong></div>
```

You'll still be able to *delete* the "Hi there" but not edit it directly.

Alternatively, you can structure your HTML like so:

```css
div {
  height: 250px;
}
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div><strong>Hi there</strong> <p contenteditable="true"></p></div>
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  If this answer worked for you, please mark it answer so other users can easily find it if searching for the same problem.  Thanks again!